# Run "git pull --rebase" in interactive mode?

Tags: git

Is it possible to run the command `git pull --rebase` in an interactive mode (like `git rebase -i`)?

Comment: Note: git 2.8 (March 2016) will allow for a `git pull --rebase=interactive command`. I have edited [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29717607/6309)

Comment: With Git 2.19 (Q3 2018), that will be `git pull --rebase=i`

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Original answer (April 2015)

<del>Not really</del>, considering a [`git pull --rebase` is not the same as a `git fech` + `git rebase`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11531502/6309).
See [what does "`git pull --rebase`" do?](http://gitolite.com/git-pull--rebase.html)

---

Update January 2016

Git 2.8 (March 2016) will allows to have a `pull --rebase` interactive!

See [commit 17c4ddb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/17c4ddbbaf5842ee6389f6a0f525c40d15152b55), [commit b5496d4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b5496d484d244bc291db0973466b76e7f679cb9f), [commit f5eb87b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f5eb87b98dd6aa587683057b9f5bd063e682e145) (13 Jan 2016) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit f9219c0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f9219c0b3233229c6686224dfc953e5b3fe92a84), 26 Jan 2016)</sup>

> ### `pull`: allow interactive rebase with `--rebase=interactive`
>
> A couple of years ago, I found the need to collaborate on topic branches that were rebased all the time, and I really needed to see what I was rebasing when pulling, so I introduced an interactively-rebasing pull.
>
> The way builtin pull works, this change also supports the value '`interactive`' for the '`branch.<name>.rebase`' config variable, which
>   is a neat thing because users can now configure given branches for
>   interactively-rebasing pulls without having to type out the complete
>   `--rebase=interactive` option every time they pull.

---

Update August 2018, Git 2.19:

"`git pull --rebase=interactive`" learned "`i`" as a short-hand for
"`interactive`".

See [commit 46af44b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/46af44b07dd433c073778f0d5ab27d0167dbcec4) (04 Aug 2018) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit c757aa2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c757aa2d12ceeb5a86c2da8ad1e9e752625af739), 17 Aug 2018)</sup>

> ### `pull --rebase=<type>`: allow single-letter abbreviations for the type
>
> 'Git for Windows' original [4aa8b8c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4aa8b8c82837a7f4aa742ba49f3461d827dff4ee) (Teach 'git pull' to handle
>   --rebase=interactive, 2011-10-21) had support for the very convenient
>   abbreviation
>
> ```
> git pull --rebase=i
> ```
>
> which was later lost when it was ported to the builtin `git pull`, and
>   it was not introduced before the patch eventually made it into Git as
>   [f5eb87b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f5eb87b98dd6aa587683057b9f5bd063e682e145) (`pull`: allow interactive rebase with `--rebase=interactive`,
>   2016-01-13, Git 2.8.0).
>
> However, it is *really* a useful short hand for the occasional rebasing
>   pull on branches that do not usually want to be rebased.
>
> So let's reintroduce this convenience, at long last.

---

With Git 2.26 (Q1 2020), "[`git remote`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote) `rename X Y`" needs to adjust configuration variables (e.g. `branch.<name>.remote`) whose value used to be `X` to `Y`.
`branch.<name>.pushRemote` is now also updated.

See [commit b3fd6cb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b3fd6cbf29435f8b49a0a5d9f86236e00b084624) (01 Feb 2020), and [commit f2a2327](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f2a2327a4a6a9bccade6df2bed1fdc3a8ab37f4c), [commit 923d4a5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/923d4a5ca4f86c19247ef436e6d03d261ebce904), [commit ceff1a1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ceff1a13084bba74b607d738c6c467365aa6a5f7), [commit 1a83068](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1a83068c26206d2b45718e0896955eb61bef8353), [commit 88f8576](https://github.com/git/git/commit/88f8576eda2880587fb4487ba469d909dbe35a7b) (27 Jan 2020) by [Bert Wesarg (`bertwesarg`)](https://github.com/bertwesarg).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit d0038f4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d0038f4b31d6ab1f0602a4d3c19e35c5004175fa), 25 Feb 2020)</sup>

> ### [`pull --rebase/remote rename`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/88f8576eda2880587fb4487ba469d909dbe35a7b): document and honor single-letter abbreviations rebase types
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Bert Wesarg</sup>
>
> When [46af44b07d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/46af44b07dd433c073778f0d5ab27d0167dbcec4) ("`pull --rebase=<type>`: allow single-letter abbreviations for the type", 2018-08-04, Git v2.19.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c757aa2d12ceeb5a86c2da8ad1e9e752625af739) listed in [batch #7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fa03cdc39b951d1cfbfd690fe6f3ac6c57ab6a44)) landed in Git, it had the side effect that not only '`pull --rebase=<type>`' accepted the single-letter abbreviations but also the '`pull.rebase`' and '`branch.<name>.rebase`' configurations.
>
> However, '[`git remote`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote) `rename`' did not honor these single-letter abbreviations when reading the '`branch.*.rebase`' configurations.
>
> We now document the single-letter abbreviations and both code places share a common function to parse the values of '`git pull --rebase=*`', '`pull.rebase`', and '`branches.*.rebase`'.
>
> The only functional change is the handling of the `branch_info::rebase` value.
>   Before it was an unsigned enum, thus the truth value could be checked with `branch_info::rebase != 0`. But `enum rebase_type` is signed, thus the truth value must now be checked with `branch_info::rebase >= REBASE_TRUE`

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to update this! Finding the most recent updates was a tough task!